# Who is Lucifer's mother in the eponymous TV-show?

Tags: character, lucifer

In final episode of the first season of *Lucifer* we saw that the mother of Lucifer escaped hell.

Who is the mother of Lucifer? And why is she in hell? Is there any explanation in the comics?

And who will play the mother?

Comment: Since you are asking about the comics, you might have better luck getting and answer on [Sci-Fi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com); as far as I know the comics have nothing to say about his mother -- or if he even has one -- but there are some major DC comic experts over there.

Comment: Unknown (for now except maybe the scenarists): http://tvline.com/2016/04/25/lucifer-season-1-finale-mom-escapes-hell/
A possibility could by like "Eve" in Supernatural, the mother of all monsters (except leviathans, angels and demons), and "Mum" is just a nickname, maybe not here real name, but a way that everyone calls her mom, like "everyone" say Dad to God.

Comment: Darkness from Supernatural best as Mum I think))

Comment: 20k views in 2 days? Seriously?

Comment: Now we know) http://lucifer.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Richards

Comment: What I find notable about Lucifer's "Mum" is that she has been identified as the "goddess" wife of God. This implies that God is not the one and only deity. The existence of a "Mrs. God" suggests that God copulated with this goddess to bring forth his children (Lucifer and the angels, for example). This could make sense, according to the Bible, that states that man [humans] were made "in God's image." By extension, it could mean that God had a sexual physique, like Adam, His first human creation. I believe that religious Orthodox would consider Lucifer's Mum to be very offensive. Ardent Christ

Answer (score 5):

In the comics Lucifer and his brother Michael are spontaneously created by their father Yahweh in order to act as the catalysts of creation. Michael was given the demiurgic power to create, while Lucifer was given unending Will which he used to shape creation.

The only motherly figure in the series is that of Lilith, the first woman. Her countless relations with men produced her army of offspring known as the Lilim. Mazikeen is one of the eldest and becomes the leader of the Lilim later in the comics. It seems highly unlikely for them to use this version of Lilith since she has offspring with Gabriel and speaks with Lucifer in her bedchambers, acting as more of a confidant than anything in the eyes of Lucifer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the first episode of Season 2, Lucifer's mother is another "celestial being" of roughly the same sort as Lucifer's father, God.

Lucifer's parents "begat" all of creation, including the higher angels, who refer to them as "mom" and "dad". So far, "mom" has not been given any other name on the show.

According to Lucifer, when God cast him out of heaven, mom did nothing to help him, leaving him feeling abandoned. Later, as God spent more time with humanity and less with her, mom lashed out and started sending natural disasters to Earth. God responded by casting her into hell. Lucifer chose to do nothing, leaving his mother locked up in Hell (where apparently Maze tortured her).

In the show, she's being played by Tricia Helfer, of *Battlestar Galactica* fame. (In a cool easter egg, her first appearance on the show was preceded by Lucifer playing "All Along The Watchtower" on the piano.)